# jQuery lightbox doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, lightbox

Take a look at this site, http://www.uniquegeeks.co.uk/product/test-LED%20Lights-0001#, and please work out why it works perfectly in every other browser but IE.

1. The problem is that in IE the site is off to the left and every other browser it's as it should be, in the middle.
2. When you click the larger image in a non IE browser, it's a working lightbox.  In IE it doesn't work and just shows the large picture underneath.

Comment: See answer by @Nick Radford below.  You cannot place a `<div>` outside of the `<body>...</body>`.  You should also run your code through the [W3C Online Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uniquegeeks.co.uk%2Fproduct%2Ftest-LED%2520Lights-0001%23&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and fix those 60 errors; some are ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

As an aside:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to it operating in quirks mode (if you press F12 in IE you'll see the 'document mode' defaults to quirks).
Set a doctype like:

```
<!doctype html>
```

To ensure it defaults to IE9 (or whatever version it actually is)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> is set

Comment: My general rule for IE: `if something isn't working right, did I set a doctype?`

Comment: @Nick Radford:  A better rule would be, _"did I [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) the code?"_ (that would catch a missing DOCTYPE too.)

Comment: @Sparky672: Validate-shmalidate ;) - As a bad rule-of-thumb, I tend to hold validation off until the end...

Comment: @Nick Radford:  The _end_ of what?  Isn't trying to figure out why your page isn't working in IE, _the end_?  And why are you waiting until the end to make sure you're following proper syntax... something that should be correct from the start.

Comment: @Sparky672: Fair enough, haha. Besides, I'm not the one wrapping an entire HTML document in a div. I hope I'm not coming off as functionally retarded, I _do_ validate my code, the `Validate-schmalidate` comment was meant to be facetious.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that your `<div id="wrapper">` is being carried to the top of your html for some reason. I only see this if I view source, if I view html through debugger tools that div is placed correctly after the body tag.

Comment: That's probably firebug/debugger magic. @Lee probably misunderstood the docs for light box and read 'body' to mean 'all of the html'. I doubt this is causing the IE error, he's since added a doctype, and lightbox is working again.

Comment: You're seeing something different in the browser debugger because the browser itself dynamically tries to fix certain open or misplaced tags in the DOM.  Either way, wrapping a `<div>` around `<head>...</body>` is not correct at all.

Comment: Yeah after posting I realized that the browser was probably just trying to fix the tag but I wasn't sure. This is good to know, thanks.